# aws cognito verification email using parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

can I use email as parameter in aws cognito verification email?

tried this:

```
You can verify your account here: <a href="http://localhost:8080/{####}/{email}">verification Link</a>
```

{####} works fine bute {email} not

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are referring to the "{email}" as a placeholder that Cognito will recognize and replace the value of the email for that user. So if you mean this is not supported.

However, Cognito provides a way through lambda to customize your verification message. Here are the [details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-custom-message)

It is easier to create a dynamic FQDN in the lambda trigger  - so the developer can place the email at the appropriate place the message (or uri)

Here's an example of a custom message lambda function

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
// 
if(event.userPoolId === "theSpecialUserPool") {
    // Identify why was this function invoked
    if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {
        // Ensure that your message contains event.request.codeParameter. This is the placeholder for code that will be sent
        event.response.smsMessage = "Welcome to the service. Your confirmation code is " + event.request.codeParameter;
        event.response.emailSubject = "Welcome to the service";
        event.response.emailMessage = "Thank you for signing up. " + event.request.codeParameter + " is your verification code";
    }
    // Create custom message for other events
}
// Customize messages for other user pools

//

// Return result to Cognito
context.done(null, event);
};
```

Comment: do you know a good example for invoking the cognito service with lamda?

Comment: You mean providing to Cognito a lambda that invokes internally? or how to call Cognito from lambda function

Comment: to make a custom message that is send when aws cognito tries to send mails. For Example verification for user. New Password Verification.

Answer (score 4):

Choose the lambda function which is going to trigger your custom messages, in my case is `CognitoCustomMessage`:

[image]

Inside this lambda function you can get the "email", "name", etc from your `userAttributes` like:

```
if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {
  const { codeParameter, userAttributes: { name, email } } = event.request;

  event.response.emailSubject = "Welcome to ...";
  event.response.emailMessage = `Welcome ${name}, this is your verification 
  code ${codeParameter}.`;
}
```

See a complete list of [**AWS Lambda Triggers**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-shared.html)